# Using prettify on StackOverflow for syntax highlighting code

Tags: syntax-highlighting, prettify

I just knew that I can syntax highlight code blocks here using Prettify but I don't really get the idea. Somebody edited my other question by highlighting my code but I would like to know how I can do it myself so I can present my code problems in a nicer way.

I followed other similar question and answer here and downloaded Prettify source files comprised with set of javascript but I don't expect to upload any of those on StackOverflow to be able to syntax highlight my code here.

Can anyone explain this in a way that I can understand?

Comment: I think meta.stackoverflow.com might be a better place to ask this question, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks, I spotted similar questions here so I thought it would be okay to post my question here...